# Geometrical interpretation (argument of $\frac{z+1}{i} = \frac{3}{2} \pi$)

Tags: complex-numbers

I'd like to ask you about a way to draw geometrical interpretation of this equation:

$\arg\left(\frac{z+1}{i}\right) = \frac{3\pi}{2}$

What I did:

$\arg\left(\frac{z+1}{i}\right) = \arg(z+1) + \arg(-i) = \arg(z+1) - \frac{\pi}{2} = \frac{3\pi}{2} $

Then:

$\arg(z+1) = 2\pi = 0$

But how to draw it? Is it just "X Axis line"?

Comment: What about noting that this is equivalent to $\frac{z+1}i=-ix$ with $x>0$, that is, to $z=x-1$. Thus the set of solutions is the horizontal halfline $(-1,+\infty)$ subset of the real line in the complex plane.

Comment: Thank you. If it was just $arg(z) = 0$ I can draw it as $(0, +\infty)$ halfline?

Comment: Indeed. $ $ $ $

Comment: @Did, by the way... What is the reason that $-1$ or $0$ is excluded in this case? Is this because $arg(0)$ is undefined?

Comment: Yep. $ $ $ $ $ $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credits to [Did](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/6179/did).

$\arg (z+1)=0$

Let's say that $a = z + 1$ for $a > 0$ (because of the undefined $arg(0)$

Then $a = x + 1 + yi$, where $y = 0$

$a = x + 1 \rightarrow x = a - 1$

$x \in (-1, +\infty)$

[image]